# При повороте экрана исчезает EditText

Tags: android, java

Что можно сделать? EditText изначально невидимый (invisible), я так понимаю, что при повороте экрана он снова invisible становится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("count", cnt);

    // тут сохраняем переменные 
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
  }

 protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    cnt = savedInstanceState.getInt("count");
    ф
    // восстанавливаем состояние 
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
  }
```